# How to determine Density Value of a Z-Score?

Tags: z-score, density-estimation

In this [paper](http://www.researchpublish.com/download.php?file=Method%20of%20Successive%20Interval-3247.pdf&act=book)  the authors are demonstrating the conversion of Ordinal data to Interval data. In the Step No. 7 on Page 360, they are talking about Density values of corresponding Z-values. They are suggesting to find those values in the "normal curve size table". They referred to a table named Table 1 but there was no Table 1 included with the paper. Moreover, I searched over the Internet and didn't find any such table except Z-Score table. Where can I find this table of Density values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density value is just the value of the probability density function of the standard normal distribution.

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \tag{1}$$

For example in the paper step No. 7

$Z1 = –1.76 \rightarrow  DZ1 = 0.08478$

which is just plug $-1.76$ into above formula $(1)$  which is $1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-1.76^2/2)\approx 0.08478$

or you can use R $dnorm$ function to check.

```
dnorm(-1.76,0,1)
```

The result is

```
 [1] 0.08477636
```